# Showing an identity for the geometrical distribution

Tags: probability

> Let X be geometrically distributed. Show that $$\mathbb P(X=n+k|X>n)=\Bbb P(X=k) $$ for $n,k \geq 1$.

My Attempt:
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X=n+k|X>n) &= \frac{\mathbb P(X=n+k, X>n)}{\mathbb P(X>n)} \\
                     &= \frac{\mathbb P(X=n+k)}{\mathbb P(X>n)} \\
                     &=\frac{p(1-p)^{n+k}}{1-p \sum_{l=0}^n (1-p)^l} \\
                     &= \frac{p(1-p)^{n+k}}{1-p\left(\frac{1-(1-p)^{n+1}}{1-(1-p)}\right)}\\
                    &= \frac{p(1-p)^{n+k}}{(1-p)^{n+1}}\\
                    &= p(1-p)^{k-1}.
\end{align}

But I should get $\mathbb P(X=k)=p(1-p)^k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that there are two different definitions of a geometric random variable.

One is the number of trials up to and including the first success, so has possible values $\{1,2,...\}$ and $P(X=n)=p(1-p)^{n-1}$.

The other is the number of failures before the first success, so has possible values $\{0,1,2,...\}$ and $P(X=n)=p(1-p)^{n}$.

The question is assuming the first definition, and you are using the second.  The result isn't true using the second definition, and what you got - that $P(X=n+k\mid X>n)=P(X=k-1)$ - would be correct. An alternative way to phrase this which looks more natural is $P(X=n+k\mid X\geq n)=P(X=k)$ for the second definition.